# Git does not produce a new commit when merging A->B then B->A, how do I make sure other teams see the second merge?

Tags: git, version-control, devops, atlassian-sourcetree

Git does not produce a new commit when merging A->B then B->A, how do I make sure other teams see the second merge?
I merged A->B to pull in latest from other devs so that QA can test with my changes plus all others also.
Now I need B->A to push the main branch to remote with my changes.
This second merge does not produce a new commit.
It may update history but no new commit.
So to other devs it looks like nothing happened.
Also using sourcetree gui for git does not issue a notification as it usualy would when it detects new commits have been pushed to remote.
What are my options for a new commit?
Obviously adding a line to some random file is an option but is also an annoying addition to the process.
Thanks in advance for advice.

Comment: You don't get a merge commit because this is a fast-forward update. You can force creating the merge commit on fast-forward updates with the `-no-ff` option. `git help merge` will give you more details.

Comment: OK I think that might work, will test it now.

Comment: @Zeitounator That works, thanks!

Comment: @Zeitounator You can answer if you want credit.

Comment: Why you want a second commit to appear in the history is unclear to me... Don't you want a history as linear as possible? It's easier to grasp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't get a merge commit because this is a fast-forward update.

You can force creating the merge commit on fast-forward updates with the `--no-ff` option.

`git help merge` will give you more details.